# R functions: use argument as name within the function

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have created a user function in R to multiply two columns to create a third (within a series), so this function creates 4 new columns.

```
create_mult_var <- function(.data){
  .data <-.data%>%
    mutate(Q4_1_4 = Q4_1_2_TEXT*Q4_1_3_TEXT) %>% 
    mutate(Q4_2_4 = Q4_2_2_TEXT*Q4_2_3_TEXT) %>%
    mutate(Q4_3_4 = Q4_3_2_TEXT*Q4_3_3_TEXT) %>%
    mutate(Q4_4_4 = Q4_4_2_TEXT*Q4_4_3_TEXT)
  .data
```

I am trying to modify this function so that I can apply it to a different set of columns that match the same type. For instance, if I want to repeat this on the series of columns that start with "Q8", I know I can do the following:

```
create_mult_var_2 <- function(.data){
  .data <-.data%>%
    mutate(Q8_1_4 = Q8_1_2_TEXT*Q8_1_3_TEXT) %>% 
    mutate(Q8_2_4 = Q8_2_2_TEXT*Q8_2_3_TEXT) %>%
    mutate(Q8_3_4 = Q8_3_2_TEXT*Q8_3_3_TEXT) %>%
    mutate(Q8_4_4 = Q8_4_2_TEXT*Q8_4_3_TEXT)
  .data
  
}
```

Instead of creating a different function for each of the Q4 and Q8 series, I would like to add the "Q4" or "Q8" as an argument. I tried this below, but R would not accept this as an argument this way. Is there a way to achieve my desired outcome?

This does not work:

```
create_mult_var <- function(.data,question){
   .data <-.data%>%
   mutate(question_1_4 = question_1_2_TEXT*question_1_3_TEXT) %>% 
   mutate(question_2_4 = question_2_2_TEXT*question_2_3_TEXT) %>%
   mutate(question_3_4 = question_3_2_TEXT*question_3_3_TEXT) %>%
   mutate(question_4_4 = question_4_2_TEXT*question_4_3_TEXT)
  .data
   
}
```

I would like to modify the function, such as that I can use the following:

```
data_in %>% create_mult_var("Q4") %>% create_mult_var("Q8")
```

Or something similar to create these new columns? Any suggestions are appreciated! Thank you! If this is a bad idea, any suggestions for how I should approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `paste` and evaluate with `!!`

```
create_mult_var_2 <- function(.data, pat){
  .data <-.data%>%
    mutate(!! str_c(pat, '_1_4') :=
    !! rlang::sym(str_c(pat, '_1_2_TEXT')) *
    !! rlang::sym(str_c(pat, '_1_3_TEXT')))
  .data 
 }

create_mult_var_2(data_in, "Q4")
#  Q4_1_2_TEXT Q4_1_3_TEXT Q4_1_4
#1           1           5      5
#2           2           6     12
#3           3           7     21
#4           4           8     32
```

---

Also, based on the pattern showed, this can be automated as well

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
create_mult_var_3 <- function(.data, pat) {
  .data %>%
    mutate(across(matches(str_c("^", pat, "_\\d+_2")), ~
               .* get(str_replace(cur_column(), '_2_TEXT', '_3_TEXT')),
         .names =  '{.col}_new')) %>%
    rename_at(vars(ends_with('_new')),
        ~ str_replace(., '\\d+_TEXT_new', '4'))



}
```

-testing

```
create_mult_var_3(data_in, "Q4")
#  Q4_1_2_TEXT Q4_1_3_TEXT Q4_1_4
#1           1           5      5
#2           2           6     12
#3           3           7     21
#4           4           8     32
```

#### data

```
data_in <- data.frame(Q4_1_2_TEXT = 1:4, Q4_1_3_TEXT = 5:8)
```

Comment: thank you! This is neat to create ONE of the variables (Q4_1_4), I need to create 4 variables for every question type (Q4_2_4, Q4_3_4 & Q4_4_4), Q4. I modified your answer to create all four but I am getting an error:

Comment: @NewBee What is the error?  I showed only onebecause it is easier to copy/paste and create more

Comment: !!rlang::sym(str_c(pat,  : 
  could not find function ":="

Comment: @NewBee Can you show your `packageVersion('dplyr')`

Comment: > packageVersion('dplyr')
[1] ‘1.0.2

Comment: @NewBee I used the same version.  May be your `packageVersion('rlang')` is older?

Comment: create_mult_var <- function(.data, pat){
  .data <-.data%>%
    mutate(!! str_c(pat, '_1_4') :=
             !! rlang::sym(str_c(pat, '_1_2_TEXT')) *
             !! rlang::sym(str_c(pat, '_1_3_TEXT'))) %>% 
    mutate(!!str_c(pat,'_2_4' :=
                     !! rlang::sym(str_c(pat, '_2_2_TEXT')) *
                     !! rlang::sym(str_c(pat, '_2_3_TEXT'))))
  .data 
}

Comment: Thanks, I re-installed both and got a new error:  Error: `:=` can only be used within a quasiquoted argument

Comment: @NewBee Can you try on a fresh R session as it is working fine with the example data I created.  Can you test that on that data in my post

Comment: @NewBee The second set of code should automatically do that.  Have you tested it

Comment: the function you created works--it's the function that I modified to add more variables that does not work (pasted my function in the comment above)

Comment: @NewBee Can you try the function `create_mult_var_3`

Comment: @NewBee If you can update your post with the function you modiffied, i can test it

Comment: @NewBee I am guessing that there is a simple typo with `,` or so that causes the error